# QEMU + KVM (Keyboard, Video and Mouse) what are my options?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, qemu

I'm using QEMU with KVM (kernel based virtualization) and I want to connect my virtual machines to my physical KVM (keyboard, video and mouse) switch.

GPU passthrough *would* be an option but I don't have enough space in my server case + not enough PCIe slots on my motherboard to do that.

What I had in mind was to somehow get around this by using an USB<>VGA converter (PCIe passthrough + USB PCIe Card).

However, as I read, it's not possible for a BIOS to utilize such an adapter because the BIOS lacks the needed drivers.

Okay, so is there a way to get around that limitation and tell QEMU somehow that it should provide a USB<>VGA adapter to a VM as a "native" VGA device?

The only thing I want to achieve is to be able to "switch" into my virtual machines with my physical KVM switch. I don't really care about how I'm going to accomplish that.

Comment: Why the want for 'native' video out? You are probably going to have an easier time working with some flavour of remote desktop or VM management software

Comment: @JourneymanGeek The "want" for "native" video out would be to be able to "switch" into the "BIOS" of a VM -- it's not a need _per se_. Since I moved from a physical setup (one server per task) to a completely virtual environment (one server for everything), I would like to still use my KVM switch to "switch" into the different servers i.e. VMs. If it's not possible to make it work with the "BIOS" then switching into a VM after its "booted" (via USB) is good enough. I thought I'd ask if someone might know a solution to this though.

Comment: Depending on your setup, there ought to be either a 'native' graphical console option - accessible via a hypervisor manager like [virt-manager](https://virt-manager.org) or the [gui from proxmox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxmox_Virtual_Environment). *Alternatively* You can set up a VNC session for your VM - they'd need to be seperate ports on the host per VM I believe. I've never needed to do so (taking the former options). You generally *wouldn't* set up a 'separate' graphical output *per* VM

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I'm already familiar with QEMU and the built-in VNC capability - it works just fine. However, connecting via VNC is not the same as having a "keyboard, video and mouse" connected directly to the VM. For the former you need a VNC client, and it is possible to "escape" the VNC viewer ; this generally not possible with KVM (I think there's a very special key-combo and I also think you could disable that). As said, it's not _really_ a problem, just curious if someone has done something similar.

Comment: I think the real oddity here is just that you said your focus was about "BIOS". I have no experience in using DisplayLink-ish USB-VGA adapter with SeaBIOS or OVMF, but the bottom line is, it would work with the guest OS if the guest OS supports it, so you should at least tell what guest you are using. But certainly, USB / PCIe passthrough are somewhat prone to hiccup (much better these days tho). And you don't even need the latter or a dedicated USB host controller card if you really just need to passthrough a USB device.

Comment: Besides, don't expect any 3D or even 2D acceleration from those DisplayLink-ish adapter. You'll be getting somewhat a "remote desktop experience" from them, I think (well, without latency or so).

Comment: @TomYan My focus isn't on "BIOS" - as stated in the question, my focus is how can I repurpose my KVM Switch to work with virtual machines instead of real ones. Besides, I've actually re-read my question and I stated USB<>VGA which at the time of writing I thought would imply that this is not going to be for performance applications. It's actually for command line operation ONLY ; not for gaming or alike.

Comment: After a second thought PCIe passthrough is actually necessary, since you can't passthrough a USB port (but just the device), which would be a problem for "KVM" setup. But then, what's the real question? (Are you really just looking for some "it-will-work" reassurance or actual qemu args?) Ah btw, PCIe passthrough requires working VT-d (not the same as VT-x) or AMD-equivalent.

Comment: `However, as I read, it's not possible for a BIOS to utilize such an adapter because the BIOS lacks the needed drivers.` AFAICT, this claim is a FUD, unless it's talking about the fact that *your* computer has no working VT-d (which is not a driver).

Comment: @TomYan Yes, PCIe passthrough would be necessary because I'm aware you can only passthrough devices on the same IOMMU group - which would mean passing through the entire I/O of my motherboard - if that's even possible, I don't know. I have VT-d support on both my motherboard and CPU, that isn't an issue. Even tested it with a network card, so that seems to work just fine. The real question is two-fold: will it work¹ and is there another, possibly better, way of doing what I wanna do. I'm aware that is not a common setup, but I really liked the way of KVM switching into my servers.

Comment: ¹ I'm currently not able to test my idea with USB and VGA adapter, but that question is really of low importance, since I can do the testing myself. I'm more eager to hear if someone else has a better idea of achieving what I wanna do. The drawback of USB<>VGA Adapter would be that it won't work until the VM has booted, which might be FUD, as said, I haven't tested it _yet_ and it wouldn't be _too_ bad. It's more curiosity than _actual need_.

Comment: `The drawback of USB<>VGA Adapter would be that it won't work until the VM has booted` Actually that could be true. What I meant was since your concern was not about getting some BIOS setting page shown on your monitor, that wouldn't be a real problem, especially when you can have both the virtual display and the physical adapter on. (I misread the statement for a bit.) As for alternative, I am not seeing any other than "remote" approaches.

Comment: `on the same IOMMU group - which would mean passing through the entire I/O of my motherboard` normally PCIe add on card will not be in the same group as others if your machine has "proper" support, so it really comes down to the machine specifically.

Comment: @TomYan `normally PCIe add on card will not be in the same group as others if your machine has "proper" support, so it really comes down to the machine specifically.` - I'm aware of that. I was merely agreeing on that I would need PCIe passthrough (i.e. another PCIe card) since I can't just passthrough a _single_ USB port from my motherboard, at least I'm not aware of how that is done in a simple manner.

Comment: @TomYan `As for alternative, I am not seeing any other than "remote" approaches.` Alright. Then I will test my approach and report back how it went. Thank you for your time :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pleased to tell that I have found a solution *that* *seems* to work.

Here's what I did:

1.) Find a USB<>VGA adapter that works with linux. These are hard to come by and some of them are really expensive (+60$). However, I found a cheap one that seems to work, albeit a bit slow: [USB2VGA](https://i-tec.pro/en/produkt/usb2vga-2/) from i-tech.

2.) For preliminary testing I used USB-passthrough instead of PCIe-passthrough and it seemed to worked just fine:

On the host machine, identify the port the USB<>VGA adapter is connected to:

```
$ lsusb -tv

/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 5000M
    ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/10p, 480M
    ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    |__ Port 3: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbfs, 1.5M
        ID c0f4:01b0
    |__ Port 3: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbfs, 1.5M
        ID c0f4:01b0
    |__ Port 5: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=usbfs, 480M
        ID 17e9:02ee DisplayLink
```

Here we can see that the adapter is on bus 1, port 5.

Use those numbers to direct QEMU to pass them through:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 \
    -enable-kvm \
    -cpu host \
    [... more config ...] \
    -usb \
    -device usb-host,hostbus=1,hostport=5
```

The important part is `-usb` and `-device`.

Finally, (it took me a while to find this) to make it work change the linux parameters inside the VM to be:

`nomodeset fbcon=map:1 vt.default_utf8=0` [(source)](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-installation-40/how-to-get-displaylink-usb-to-show-text-console-4175527644/#post5289394)

You can change the linux kernel parameters inside `/etc/default/grub` if you're using grub.

I'm not entirely sure what `vt.default_utf8=0` is for at the time of writing and maybe it can be omitted.

**However, without these kernel parameters it will NOT work with Ubuntu Server (tested 22.04.01 LTS) out of the box.**